# the else if section of this program is not working?

Tags: java

```
package Game;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String jack = "good, how are you?";
        System.out.println("Hello, my name is Julie the Robot");

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("How Are You?");

        if (jack.equals(sc.nextLine())); {
        System.out.println("Im Doing Great!");
        }
        // this code is giving me an error
        else if (!jack.equals(sc.nextLine()));{


            System.out.println("Oh! So you dont care about me eh?");
        }

        try{
            Thread.sleep(700);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
            System.out.print("...");
        try{
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex1) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }   
        System.out.print("And Yes, I'm A Canadian");



    } 
}
```

I'm trying to run this piece of code but it's highlighting the else if portion and not letting me run it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your IDE will actually show you compilation errors somewhere. (Like if you mouseover the highlight.) Read them and work from there, and at the very least tell us the error message and point out in your code where the error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove that semicolon `;` from `if();{`  and `else if ();{`

Answer (score 1):

You are using semi-colons incorrectly

```
if (jack.equals(sc.nextLine()))[;]<--don't need this {
System.out.println("Im Doing Great!");
}
else if (!jack.equals(sc.nextLine()))[;]<--don't need this either{
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

The syntax of if, else, else if, while, do, for... is inherited from C/C++.

The syntax of if, we'll use as an example, is like this:

`if (header) statement`

What is a statement? A statement is anything like this:

`function();`

`{ statement1; statement2; }`

`;`

`x = x + 1;`

A statement is 'one executable unit of code' in layman's terms. Note that `{...}` is one statement (here, `{ }` is syntax for 'everything within these curly braces should be treated as one statement) and `;` is also just one statement (it is the statement that does nothing at all).

So `if (condition);` evaluates the condition, and if it's true does nothing, else skips doing nothing. ... You can see why that might make your code break.

Similarly:

```
else if (condition);

else;

while (condition);

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i);

do; { } while (condition);
```

are all broken as the `;` is considered the one statement that the construct will execute if the condition holds. Now that you know the reason why these semicolons break flow constructs you will be able to avoid them in future and know why.